# Find the unknown area by different methods

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, puzzle, area

this problem has many ways of calculating, could provide some solutions, particularly using proportions

**EDIT : A it's not midpoint**
[image]

Comment: Is $A$ the midpoint of $CB$? (It seems so, in which case you will notice that $ABF$ is a quarter of the total rectangle area.

Comment: "Is A the midpoint of CB? (It seems so,..)"  That is not a good enough reason to make any such assumption.

Comment: "Is A the midpoint of CB?"  No.  It most certainly is not.

Comment: I'm *pretty sure* this question has been asked here before, but I can't find it at the moment. There could be other approaches in answers there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we view $AEB$ as having base $AE$ and triangle $FEB$ as have base $FE$, then the both have the same height--- the altitude of line $AF$ to point $B$.

Since triangles $AEB$ and $FEB$ both have the same height then their bases are in proportion to their areas.  So $EF = \frac 32 AE$.

Triangle $DEF$ is similar $AEB$ and the sides are that $EF$ corresponds to $AE$ and so the sides are $\frac 32$ as long.  So the area of the $DEF$ (white) area is $2cm^2 *(\frac 32)^2 = 4.5 cm^2$.

So the area of the white plus the yellow is $4.5cm^2 + 3cm^2 = 7.5 cm^2$.

As this is a rectangle triangles $DCB$ and $DFB$ are congruent and have the same area.

And so the area of the blue plus the green is $7.5 cm^2$.  So the area of the blue is $7.5 cm^2 - 2cm^2 = 5.5 cm^2$

Comment: I think there are several places where you have $B$ and mean $F$. "One decimal place accuracy" is s strange request since your answer is exact if the inputs are.

Comment: ""One decimal place accuracy" is s strange request since your answer is exact if the inputs are. "  Yeah, I thought so too.  I wonder if one method was to solve for one the the sides which are probably an irrational root.  "I think there are several places where you have B and mean F"  Yikes.  In the first paragraph even...

Comment: Regarding the "one decimal place," there seems to be a tendency (especially in software systems that grade homework) to specify the format of results in this fashion.

Comment: @fleablood ,hi ..   I must be very sleepy, I do not see what you say  **Since triangles AEB and FEB both have the same height**

Comment: Turn the picture sideways so that the base of the triangles are $AE$ and $EF$.  Then both triangles have point $B$ on the top and they are both the same height.

Comment: @Walter Draw the perpendicular from point B to segment AF. The length of that perpendicular is the height of both triangles.

Comment: @Bungo, Now I see it, I was seeing something else, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints toward different approaches:

1. The shoelace algorithm allows you to calculate the area of any polygon given that you know the coordinates of their vertices
2. The law of cosines paired with the formula for the area of any triangle could also be useful.  The law of cosines states that for triangle $ABC$, with side lengths $a,b,c$ which are the sides opposite to the angles they correspond with, that $a^2=b^2+c^2-2ab(cos(A))$ and the area of any triangle is $\frac{1}{2}ab(cos(C))$

These are obviously not answers, if you are looking for new ways to break down those geometries, these are both powerful methods.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly shorter: Let $w$ be the width of the rectangle, $h$ the height, and let $x$ be the length of segment $AB$. Argue as in @fleablood's answer (+1) that $AE=\frac23 EF$. By similar triangles, conclude $x=\frac23 w$.

The area of triangle $\triangle ABF$ is then $\frac12xh=\frac13wh$. Since this equals $5$, the area of the rectangle is $wh=15$.

Answer (score -1):

Area of the triangle $ABF=5$.

And $A$ is the midpoint of the side $CB$.

So the area of rectangle $BCDF$= 4 × area  of triangle$ ABF$
$=4×5= 20$.

Thus area of the triangle $BDC$ is half of the area of the rectangle =$10$.

Thus area of the blue reigion= $10-2=8$.

Comment: "And A is the midpoint of the side CB."  WHY???  And no, it isn't.